# Not able to install ubuntu 18.04.4 alongside windows 10 on inspiron 15 7590

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I just bought a dell inspiron 15 7590 a week ago. My specs are:

1. Intel® Core™ i7-9750H 9th generation (up to 4.5GHz, 6 cores, cache 12Mo)
2. 16Go (1x16Go) memory DDR4 2666MHz
3. Graphic cardNVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 with 3Go of graphic memoiry GDDR5
4. SSD 512Go PCIe NVMe M.2
5. Windows 10 was already installed.

The thing is that I am having problems when trying to install ubuntu 18.04.4 alongside Windows 10.

I followed the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1ykDpSzpKU to download the ubuntu 18.04.4 image and produce a bootable USB stick. As explained in the video, I did it using Rufus 3.0, which I downloaded from the rufus.akeo.ie web page.

I also,

1. Followed the instructions in here: https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10 to disable the fast startup in Windows 10.
2. I followed the instruction in this link https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr/fr/frdhs1/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-1... to

   - Set up the install partitions. I leaved around 100 GB to Windows and the rest (around 400 GB) for the ubuntu installation
   - Setup the BIOS settings. I was able to disable the secure boot (3rd screenshot in the link, Secure Boot -> Secure Boot Enable), but I wasn't able to do the following steps

     - to set the BIOS to UEFI as shown in the first screenshot in the link (General -> Boot Sequence), as in my case the were no"Legacy" or "UEFI" options in the boot list option
     - to disable Legacy option ROMS, as in the second screenshot in the link, as in my case there was no tick to uncheck for "Enable Legacy Option ROMs". I did check the tick "Enable UEFI Network Stack".

Any way, I proceeded with this BIOS settings and rebooted the laptop. I did F12 and choose to boot from the usb disk. The system responded with the following error message

`Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Fond
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed`

Looing around the internet I found a solution that was to copy the file in the usb stick in EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi to EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi

I did and I then rebooted the system again and choose install ubuntu. I then started to go through the installation wizard as usual

- Welcome page. I chosen English: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqM8e72icR0OHJXu0u9nZt3dxXh8n8_x/view?usp=sharing
- I then choose the keybord layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kW2MI48BX1qwnpmX6fhp3xnn2SHiC8D9/view?usp=sharing
- In the update and other software I checked the "install third party ..." box: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10WA6QJQlnNQ_YeTVNYk6rEer8hjoKZ3k/view?usp=sharing
- When clicking on "continue" in the previous page I got this page: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDTfzal24TAAJNLzuFkoO56IodTsAqEp/view?usp=sharing
- As you can see, the usual page where it is asked if I want to install ubuntu alongside windows doesn't show up.
- If I click on "install now" I get a little window with "No root file system: No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partioning menu"
- If I try to do something, like clicking in the + or - buttons the wizards stops.

I am a bit lost. I have been looking around for a solution but nothing works. If anybody could give me a hand, I would really appreciate it.

Many thanks in advanced,

Alejandro